# How to update react state twice in one submitHandler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, state

I  want to submit a form in React and I'm trying to update the state twice with one submitHandler. The second update depends on the first update.

```
   submitHandler(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let target      = event.target;
            let allMessages = this.props.messages;
            let title       = target.title.value,
                message     = target.message.value,
                user        = target.user.value,
                time        = `${(new Date).getHours()}:${(new Date).getMinutes()}`,
                id          = allMessages ? allMessages.length + 1 : 1;

            this.props.createNewMessage(title, message, user, time, id);
            this.props.postNewMessage(this.props.singleMessage)
        }
```

I'm creating a single message with

```
this.props.createNewMessage(title, message, user, time, id);
```

And after I create that message, I want to push the entire object in that state to an array of messages with:

```
this.props.postNewMessage(this.props.singleMessage)
```

[image]

How do I work with async and all the 'this' environments so that the new message pushed to the array with postNewMessage will have values from the new singleMessage values?

Below is how I connect create and postMewMessage:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        messages: state.messages.messages,
        title: state.singleMessage.title,
        message: state.singleMessage.message,
        user: state.singleMessage.user,
        time: state.singleMessage.time,
        singleMessage: state.singleMessage
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    createNewMessage,
    postNewMessage
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateNewPost)
```

They are defined here (in separate reducer files that will be combined through combineReducers :

```
export const addNewMessage = (message) => ({
    type: ADD_NEW_MESSAGE,
    message
})

export const postNewMessage = (newMessage) =>
    dispatch => dispatch(addNewMessage(newMessage))   

export const createMessage = (title, message, user, time, id) => ({
    type: CREATE_MESSAGE,
    title,
    message,
    user, 
    time, 
    id
})

export const createNewMessage = (title, message, user, time, id) =>
    dispatch => dispatch(createMessage(title, message, user, time, id))
```

[entire repo here](https://github.com/kaisinli/react-message-board)

Comment: You're using redux? You forget to add it in the tags. What you're looking for is probably [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) example can be found [here](https://codepen.io/amsterdamharu/pen/KRQKLj)

Comment: You mentioned async but I don't see any async code in your question. `createNewMessage` dispatches the result of `createMessage` and you dispatch the result of `addNewMessage` but what these functions do is missing.

Comment: @HMR can you look at my repo link? (hopefully this is proper stackoverflow etiquette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing asynchronous in the repo but did find one thing that was wrong in allMessageReducer.js:

```
    case ADD_NEW_MESSAGE:
        return Object.assign(
            {},
            state, 
            {messages:state.messages.concat(action.message)}
        );
```

There is a problem when trying to access `this.props.singleMessage` in CreateNewPost.js but I think that has to do with react rendering/setting the new state (maybe in requestAnimationframe).

You can see the wrong fields when logging so instead of using that it's better to just use the values you already have:

```
this.props.createNewMessage(title, message, user, time, id);
console.log(
    "state not yet available in this.props",
    JSON.stringify(this.props.singleMessage,undefined,2)
);
this.props.postNewMessage({title, message, user, time, id});
```